# How to check list of files are exists or not

Tags: vb.net

I want VB Script for checking list of files exists or not... If not exists that file name should be written in another text... I am giving input as text file... This text contain all the list of file names

Comment: VBScript or VB.net? Please show some code that you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dim filesys
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

If filesys.FileExists("c:\somefile.txt") Then
   Response.Write("File exists")
Else
   Response.Write("File does not exist")
End If
```

This will check if the file exists or not in VB Script

```
If File.Exists("c:\somefile.txt") = True Then
   Response.Write("File exists")
Else
   Response.Write("File does not exist")
End If
```

This will check if the file exists or not in VB.net  (`Imports System.IO`)

To check a list you could simply loop though the list checking each file.